# Stability of the null solution in an autonomous system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

I am supossed to study the instalibity of the null solution of the following (autonomous) system:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
x' = -x+y-x^2 \\[5pt]
y' =3x-x^2-2y
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
**My resolution so far and my problems.** Clearly we are working with an autonomous system with the form $z' = f(z)$, where $z' = [x'\hspace{.3cm} y']^T$ and $f(z) = f(x,y) = (-x+y-x^2,3x-x^2-2y)$. Obviously, $f \in C^1$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $f(0,0)=(0,0)$ ($(0,0)$ is an equilibruim point). Let's compute the Jacobian of $f$.
\begin{equation*}
J_f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix}-1-2x \quad \quad 1 \\[5pt]
3-2x \quad \quad -2
\end{pmatrix}
\Rightarrow J_f(0,0) = \begin{pmatrix}-1 \quad \quad1 \\[5pt] 3 \quad \quad -2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Now we compute the eigenvalues of $J_f(0,0)$ and we get the following result:
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_1 = \frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2} \quad \vee \quad \lambda_2 = \frac{-3-\sqrt{13}}{2}  
\end{equation*}
Which make us conclude that $J_f(0,0)$ isn't hurwitz (it has a positive real eigenvalue).

So, I can't conclude nothing about the stability of the null solution using this method. I would now try to find a Lupyanov function and use its direct method since these are the two methods I've been taught. I have tried multiple Lupyanov functions and I can't figure one out that actually works for this case. So this is my question, if someone can help me finding a Lupyanov function I would be really thankfull.

Comment: Do you really need Lyapunov function? One positive real eigenvalue and one negative real eigenvalue imply that zero is a saddle point, which is unstable: you can just solve the linear system and see it. If you want to use Lyapunov anyway, consider $V(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. You’ll see that $\nabla V  J_f(0,0) (v) > 0$ for any eigenvector $v$ corresponding to the positive eigenvalue.

Comment: Thanks @Timur Bakiev ! I have commented my further theorical doubts on Lutz answer, can you have a look at it and answer If possible?

Comment: ok, will do it later

Comment: Thanks once again :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got a strictly positive and a strictly negative eigenvalue. Thus the linearized system has a saddle point. This remains true in the local picture for the perturbation to the original non-linear system.

This kind of persistence of the characterization of the stationary point is only in doubt and can be violated if one or more of the eigenvalues is zero or has zero real part. See *" [Example of an ODE with an asymptotically stable equilibrium which is unstable in the corresponding linearization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4180808/example-of-an-ode-with-an-asymptotically-stable-equilibrium) "* for an example of how "unstable" (in a meta sense) this situation is.

Comment: Hey @Lutz Lehmann ! Thanks for your answer! Does this means that I can apply the known results for linear system (with constant coefficients) to the linearized system in all the scenarios? By this I mean the following: If the linearized system has one or more eigenvalues with real part strictly positive the null solution is instável ;; If we have ONLY eigenvalues with strictly negative real part -> assimptotically Stanley ;; If we have ONLY eigenvalues with real part negative or 0 (and If these are Simple) -> null solution stable? Thanks once again

Comment: instável means unstable and Stanley means stable. Autocorrector

Comment: Mostly yes, up to the last. If some of the eigenvalues have real part zero, then what happens really depends on the non-linear terms. As the example shows, you still can get polynomial growth. See Grobman-Hartman theorem.

Comment: I think I got it. So basically: If for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have $Re(\lambda)>0$ then we can conclude imediatly than the null solution is unstable, through Grobman-Hartman theorem. On the other hand, if for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ we have $Re(\lambda)=0$, we have to look for a Lyapunov function (since we can't conclude nothing with the pre-method). Is this right? Thanks for your time

Comment: Yes, if you find a Lyapunov function then the situation is again clear. Else you need other methods, what works can depend on the specific ODE. Sometimes the approximation of the central manifold gives sufficient information.

Comment: Thanks @Lutz Lehmann ! Really good clarification and answer!

Answer (score 1):

Method:  Set the derivatives equal to 0, graph the two parabolas.  Plug in + or- in each region separated,  to see if solutions just off (0,0) are tending towards the origin or away when you are near (0,0).  If they all trend towards, stable,  if all away unstable, otherwise semistable.

Answer (score 0):

An illustration only (hence cw):

[image]

Made with Mathematica code

```
With[{M=.01},StreamPlot[{-x+y-x^2,3x-x^2-2y},{x,-M,M},{y,-M,M}]]
```